# Two Wikipedia pages have the same Page ID

Tags: wikipedia, wikipedia-api

The Page ID definition in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Page_information
says Page ID is a **"Uniquely identifying primary key"**

Why then do these two Wikipedia pages have the same Page ID: 347833

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Norfolk_Southern_Railway&action=info

https://da.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Avery_Dennison&action=info

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is unique for a given database. `en.wikipedia.org` and `da.wikipedia.org` are two separate databases.

Comment: Thank you, this clarifies and helps. I did not find any mention of databases in the documentation. Perhaps I missed it. It would be great to have some explanation in the page id help page

Comment: Basically each domain (each Wikipedia language edition) is a separate MediaWiki installation. So, from the POV of MediaWiki documentation, it doesn't make much sense to mention that things are not unique wrt another installation of the software. (You can find some documentation on the concept of interconnected wikis at https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Wiki_family but that's aimed at people who operate wikis, not the ones who use them, so probably won't be helpful.)

Comment: Thanks again for this very concise and helpful explanation!